# Error 1001: The Specified Service Already Exists. Cannot remove existing service

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008, windows-services

I have a service. I installed it a while ago. I need to do an update to the service. I went to the Add/Remove Programs and looked for my service, and it is not installed there. I looked at services.msc and it is there, stopped. I was able to start it and stop it. I ran a command prompt as administrator and ran sc delete [Service Name], and recieved "The specified service does not exist as an installed service." I did a sc query in the command prompt, and it is not returned. I right clicked on the installer, clicked on uninstall and recieved "This action is only valid for products that are currently installed." I tried repair as well, and got the same message.

I have restarted the machine a few times, and no luck getting this service to uninstall. I'm using the basic Setup Project template installed with Visual Studio. I've tried changing the name of the program, and increasing the version number.

How do I uninstall the service that apparently exists, and prevent this happening in the future?

Comment: Just to be clear, there's a Service Name and a Service Display Name. Sometimes people forget that the "name" column in services.msc is the service's display name. You get the service name by right clicking on your services and going to properties.

Comment: @Tung I checked that, and they are both the same.

Comment: Migrate to http://www.superuser.com ?  This isn't really a programming question.

Answer (score 11):

** If it is required to be done using the setup only, please follow:

This can be handled by explicit implementation of existing service removal (uninstall) and then allowing newer version to install.
For this, we need to update ProjectInstaller.Designer.cs as below:

Consider adding following line at the beginning of InitializeComponent() which triggers an event for uninstalling the existing service before your current installer tries to install the service again. Here we uninstall the service if it already exists.

Add following namespaces:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceProcess;
```

Add below line of code as described before:

```
this.BeforeInstall += new
System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventHandler(ProjectInstaller_BeforeInstall);
```

Example:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.BeforeInstall += new System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventHandler(ProjectInstaller_BeforeInstall);

    this.serviceProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
    this.serviceInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
    // 
    // serviceProcessInstaller1
    // 
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = null;
    // 
    // serviceInstaller1
    // 
    this.serviceInstaller1.Description = "This is my service name description";
    this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "MyServiceName";
    this.serviceInstaller1.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
    // 
    // ProjectInstaller
    // 
    this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[]{
            this.serviceProcessInstaller1,
            this.serviceInstaller1
        }
    );
}
```

The below code called by the event will then uninstall the service if it exists.

```
void ProjectInstaller_BeforeInstall(object sender, System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventArgs e)
{
    List<ServiceController> services = new List<ServiceController>(ServiceController.GetServices());

    foreach (ServiceController s in services)
    {
        if (s.ServiceName == this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName)
        {
            ServiceInstaller ServiceInstallerObj = new ServiceInstaller();
            ServiceInstallerObj.Context = new System.Configuration.Install.InstallContext();
            ServiceInstallerObj.Context = Context;
            ServiceInstallerObj.ServiceName = "MyServiceName";
            ServiceInstallerObj.Uninstall(null);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

*PS: Along with the above changes, also please consider updating the setup Version, ProductCode (, and optionall UpgradeCode) for good practice, better version management, tracking and maintenance*

Comment: This is a great answer, but i found out you can get the same behaviour without manually editing ProjectInstaller.Designer.cs (this is an auto generated source file and editing is dangerous as VS can regenerate it, so you can end losing your changes). You can bind to BeforeInstall event in the property tab on serviceProcessInstaller, in the event detail panel.

Comment: @andreapier: Thank you for your comments. Yes, that's very true. This can be achieved through properties tab. Here, I just thought that it would be easier for understanding the internals. Thanks for the feedback. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Note that if you do this it applies it to your *new* setup exe, when you try to install your new setup exe the uninstall code runs from the *old* setup exe (as far as I can tell), so you may need to remove your existing installation by hand and reinstall for this code to work!

Answer (score 9):

If you have the .exe that includes the service installer use `InstallUtil.exe /u <process.exe>`
InstallUtil.exe is found in `\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319`

In the setup project, include your service in all custom actions, also the uninstall

(right click on the project, Custom Action)

hth

Mario

Answer (score 5):

It is completely normal that the service is not listed in Add/Remove Programs, that listing is for software packages, not services.  (One package, or program, may contain multiple services, but it typically installs none.)

Apparently, the service was installed manually, not as part of the product, even if this one in particular would normally install with a product whose installation package you have got.

Using `sc delete` is correct. You will need to include the (short) name of the service in double quotes (unless it is just a single word), but nothing else.

Failing that, visit `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services` in your registry, both 32 bit and 64 bit (`regedt32.exe` and `regedit.exe`, respectively).  You can even delete the service there directly, but you should obviously start by reversible changes to diagnose how is your service exactly named and why `sc` does not see its name and only use direct registry access after everything else has failed and after you have backed up your registry (google this procedure up specifying your operating system).

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me today. The only solution was to repair the setup file from Windows Add/Remove tool. After repairing your setup file uninstall and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking in the Windows Registry for some trash relating to that service?.

You should look on this folder: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Services \

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to the registry. I don't always feel comfortable going in there anyways, so I was hoping there is something I could do without going in there. I requested access to the registry, but there's a lot of red tape associated with it.

Comment: I tried to delete the folder associated to my service but the service was still showing up and then I had to restart my computer.

Comment: Manually editing the registry when working on an installer is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else comes across this issue:

What worked for me was updating the Name, Version and ProductCode of my Installer. Should definitely follow good practice of versioning anyways.

Comment: That's not related to servies at all.